# microsoft-graph obtendo somente scope user.read

Tags: oauth2, microsoft, password, scope

Olá!

Se alguem puder ajudar.
Estou tentando obter os emails de algumas contas do 365 da nossa organização para integrar com uma aplicação de CRM.
O programa é em PHP e estou tentando fazer o acesso no microsoft graph da seguinte forma:
http post em

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytenantId}/oauth2/token

passando como parametros:

```
client_id = myAppId,
client_secret = myAppPassword,
resource = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
username = vendedor@email.com.br,
password = passwordDoVendedor,
scope = 'user.read,mail.read,mail.send',
grant_type = 'password',
prompt = 'admin_consent'
```

Executando, ele retorna o access_token e o refresh_toke com status 200, porém, no scope só vem 'User.read'

Alguem saberia me dizer o que está faltando para eu ter acesso aos outros escopos?

Agradeço a ajuda

Comment: segundo a documentação o escopo é delimitado pir espaços, você ta colocando vírgula, segue documentação:https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/outlook/rest/get-started

Comment: Me encheu de esperança, mas não é isso não. Já tentei de diversos modos: 'Mail.Read' sozinho, 'Mail.Read Mail.Send', com virgula, com espaço. Obrigado pela dica. Pena não ser isso ;)